# Setting theme and palette for Angular Material components

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular Material 17.3.0 application, I'd like to be able set the theme and palette for a component. Setting a non-default theme is possible via class:

```
Select theme via class
<mat-slider [class]="themeSelected">
  <input matSliderThumb />
</mat-slider>
```

This works fine in v17. Setting the `ThemePalette` color to `primary`, `accent`, or `warn` appears to work:

```
Select theme via class and palette via color
<mat-slider [color]="paletteSelected">
  <input matSliderThumb />
</mat-slider>
```

but the displayed color is incorrect if `[class]` is added:

```
Select theme via class and palette via color
<mat-slider [class]="themeSelected" [color]="paletteSelected">
  <input matSliderThumb />
</mat-slider>
```

The component is trivial:

```
export class AppComponent {
  themeNames: string[] = ['theme-1', 'theme-2', 'theme-3'];
  themeSelected: string = this.themeNames[0];

  paletteNames: ThemePalette[] = ['primary', 'accent', 'warn'];
  paletteSelected: ThemePalette = this.paletteNames[0];
}
```

The `selectedTheme` + `selectedColor` is not selecting the correct color in the theme. Here's [a sample showing the problem](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/themed-slider).

This (mis-)behavior appears to be a precedence issue between `class` + `color` properties. Any ideas on how to make something like this work?